# Max, Min Values of $\frac{df}{ds}$ in the direction of u

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Find the max and min values of $\frac{df}{ds}$ in the direction of
> **u** as **u** varies, and tell for which directions the maximum and minimum occur. Finally, find the directions **u** for which
> $\frac{df}{ds}$ in the direction of **u** = 0.

$w = xy + yz + xz \text{ at }(1, -1,2) $

$\nabla w = \hat{i} + 3\hat{j}$

$\nabla w \cdot$ **u** $= \hat{i} + 3\hat{j} \text{ }\cdot$ **u** = $\sqrt{10}$

Is there a way to systematically solve for u? I just guessed and checked and got: $\frac{\hat{i} + 3\hat{j}}{\sqrt{10}}$. But I want to solve this systematically. Algebraically, this is what I have for max: $\dfrac{df}{ds} = \nabla f \cdot u = (1,3,0) \cdot \frac{1}{x^2+y^2+z^2}(x,y,z) = \sqrt{10}$ but I can't really solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\dfrac{df}{ds} = \nabla f \cdot u $

where $ u $ is a unit vector.  You have found that

$ \nabla f = (1, 3, 0) $

So the maximum $ \dfrac{df}{ds} $ occurs with $ u = (1, 3, 0)/\sqrt{10} $
and the minimum $ \dfrac{df}{ds} $ occurs with $ u = (-1, -3, 0) /\sqrt{10} $

If we want $\dfrac{df}{ds} = 0$, then this means that $(1, 3, 0) \cdot u = 0$

so that the vector $u = (x, y, z) $ lies in the plane $x + 3 y = 0$